# How does one extract data from a string which possibly could get split by an optional comma character?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, capture

I've gotten strings like `"Street number 1, Barcelona"`, or if there was no street data, just `"Barcelona"`, I'm trying both expressing the patterns and capturing the city data by a single regex.

I already came up with a pattern which does select everything on a string that does not contain commas ...

```
^([^,]+)$
```

I also have a regex for capturing everything after the first comma ...

```
^.+?, (.*)$
```

Is it possible to merge both into a single regex and/or how could it be managed?

Comment: `(?<=,|^)[^,]*$` would do it assuming your regex support lookbehinds.

Comment: I assume you're trying to validate an address. If that is your end goal, I STONGLY recommend you rethink your strategy. `.*` is too generic for what you are trying to do. It seems to me that, after the comma, you are trying to validate a city name. In that case, your characters after the comma are all letters (city name). I would you use that pattern instead. I also recommend stricter rules for the pattern that validates the street address. For example: "a street address consists of a series of letters followed by a number." The more specific, the less error prone your regex will be.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks, this worked fine

Comment: @hfontanez Well, this is oriented for a web crawler, i have to be less strict that i would be in other cases, anyway thanks for your recommendations

Comment: @LuisCarreteroFresno, do you want to validate a string and/or do you need to extract certain data from it?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Extract data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***just testing***

If the OP's use case was just testing, following regex might help `/^[^,]*,*[^,]+$/`. It *reads* as follows ...

- `/^ ... $/` in between start and end ...
- `[^,]*` optionally match anything that is *not a comma* ...
- `,*` maybe followed by an *optional comma* ...
- `[^,]+` followed (or standing just for itself) by at least one character which is *not a comma*.

```js
const regXOptionallySplittingComma = (/^[^,]*,*[^,]+$/);

console.log(
  'test ... "" ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("")
);
console.log(
  'test ... "," ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test(",")
);
console.log(
  'test ... " ," ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test(" ,")
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'test ... " , " ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test(" , ")
);
console.log(
  'test ... ",  " ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test(",  ")
);
console.log(
  'test ... "   " ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("   ")
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'test ... "  Barcelona  " ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("  Barcelona  ")
);
console.log(
  'test ... "Lloret de Mar" ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("Lloret de Mar")
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'test ... ",  Barcelona  " ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test(",  Barcelona  ")
);
console.log(
  'test ... ",  Lloret de Mar  " ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test(",  Lloret de Mar  ")
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'test ... "Street number 1, Barcelona" ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("Street number 1,  Barcelona")
);
console.log(
  'test ... "Street number 1, Lloret de Mar" ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("Street number 1,  Lloret de Mar")
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'test ... "Street, number 1, Barcelona" ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("Street, number 1,  Barcelona")
);
console.log(
  'test ... "Street number 1, Lloret de, Mar" ?',
  regXOptionallySplittingComma.test("Street number 1,  Lloret de, Mar")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***extracting data***

If the OP's use case was extracting data, like getting the right hand side of a string which could be split by an optional comma, a possible solution does not necessarily need to be based on a regex ...

```js
function extractTrailingNonCommaChars(str) {
  const list = String(str).split(',');

  // - without testing for a maximum two partials split
  // - take always the last or most right handed partial ...
  // return list[list.length - 1].trim();

  // - with testing for a maximum two partials split ...
  const count = list.length;
  return (count <= 2) && list[count - 1].trim() || '';
}

console.log(
  '"Street number 1,  Barcelona  " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars("Street number 1,  Barcelona  ") }"`
);
console.log(
  '",  Lloret de Mar  " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(",  Lloret de Mar  ") }"`
);
console.log(
  '" Barcelona" =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(" Barcelona") }"`
);
console.log(
  '"Lloret, de Mar" =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars("Lloret, de Mar") }"`
);

console.log(
  '",,," =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(",,,") }"`
);
console.log(
  '",  " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(",  ") }"`
);
console.log(
  '" , " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(" , ") }"`
);
console.log(
  '"   " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars("   ") }"`
);
console.log(
  '"," =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(",") }"`
);
console.log(
  '"" =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars("") }"`
);
console.log(
  '"Street, number 1,  Barcelona  " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars("Street, number 1,  Barcelona  ") }"`
);
console.log(
  '",  Lloret de, Mar  " =>',
  `"${ extractTrailingNonCommaChars(",  Lloret de, Mar  ") }"`
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll be using the regex part of this, i know its better the second one for extracting data, but due to the nature of the program and the huge amount of diferent websites i have to stick to regex and skip coding as much as possible. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^(?:.+,\s)?(.*)$
```

Here a link to verify:

https://regex101.com/r/Hak486/1/